# Writing MIPS machine instructions and executing them from C

Tags: c, assembly, mips, inline-assembly, mips32

I'm trying to write some self modifying code in C and MIPS.

Since I want to modify the code later on, I'm trying to write actual machine instructions (as opposed to inline assembly) and am trying to execute those instructions. Someone told me that it would be possible to **just malloc some memory, write the instructions there, point a C function pointer to it and then jump to it.** (I include the example below)

I've tried this with my cross compiler (sourcery codebench toolchain) and it doesn't work (yes, in hind sight I suppose it does seem rather naive). How could I properly do this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>


void inc(){
    int i = 41;
    uint32_t *addone = malloc(sizeof(*addone) * 2); //we malloc space for our asm function
    *(addone) = 0x20820001; // this is addi $v0 $a0 1, which adds one to our arg (gcc calling con)
    *(addone + 1) = 0x23e00000; //this is jr $ra

    int (*f)(int x) = addone; //our function pointer
    i = (*f)(i);
    printf("%d",i);    
}

int main(){
    inc();
exit(0);}
```

I follow the gcc calling convention here, where the arguments are passed to $a0 and the results of the functions are expected to be in $v0. I don't actually know if the return address will be put into $ra (but I can't test it yet since I can't compile.
I use int for my instructions because I'm compiling MIPS32(hence a 32 bit int should be enough)

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what happens instead?

Comment: You're storing the pointer returned by `malloc` in an int. Is the int large enough for this? Why not use a proper pointer type? Also, are you sure that your int is the correct size for an instruction?

Comment: I don't know enough about MIPS, but when I've done this kind of work (1) you need to make sure the memory has the right permissions with `mprotect` and (2) you may need to flush the instruction and data caches if the architecture has separate instruction/data caches that aren't coherent.

Comment: Remember that `jr` executes an instruction from its delay slot before transferring control to the target address (`$ra` in this case). You want a "safe" instruction (e.g. `nop`) at `*(addone + 2)`.

Comment: Or swap the order of the two instructions so the addi is in the delay slot of the jr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP's code as written compiles without errors with Codesourcery mips-linux-gnu-gcc.

As others have mentioned above, self modifying code on MIPS requires the instruction cache to be synchronized with the data cache after the code is written.  The MIPS32R2 version of the MIPS architecture added the `SYNCI` [instruction](http://books.google.com/books?id=kk8G2gK4Tw8C&pg=PA232&lpg=PA232&dq=mips%20synci&source=bl&ots=c_4Oo5MxSq&sig=uBgEiPPJpdZkPZcRWqpIVVVLKKU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=09WRUML9A4SGjAL0w4GYCQ&sqi=2&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=mips%20synci&f=false) which is a user mode instruction that does what you need here. All modern MIPS CPUs implement MIPS32R2, including `SYNCI`.

Memory protection is an option on MIPS, but most MIPS CPUs are not built with this feature selected, so using the mprotect system call is likely not needed on most real MIPS hardware.

Note that if you use any optimization besides `-O0` the compiler can and does optimize away the stores to `*addone` and the function call, which breaks your code. Using the `volatile` keyword prevents the compiler from doing this.

The following code generates correct MIPS assembly, but I don't have MIPS hardware handy to test it on:

```
int inc() {
    volatile int i = 41;
    // malloc 8 x sizeof(int) to allocate 32 bytes ie one cache line,
    // also ensuring that the address of function addone is aligned to
    // a cache line.
    volatile int *addone = malloc(sizeof(*addone) * 8);
    *(addone)     = 0x20820001; // this is addi $v0 $a0 1
    *(addone + 1) = 0x23e00000; //this is jr $ra
    // use a SYNCI instruction to flush the data written above from
    // the D cache and to flush any stale data from the I cache
    asm volatile("synci 0(%0)": : "r" (addone));
    volatile int (*f)(int x) = addone; //our function pointer
    int j = (*f)(i);
    return j;
}

int main(){
    int k = 0;
    k = inc();
    printf("%d",k);    
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't quite understand what's going on. I read in the link about the cache line. but then why do we malloc(... *4) instead of 8? Isn't the pointer also 4 bytes long?
also, when I compile your code (the only change I make is to import the headers at the beginning) I get the following assembler error: Illegal operands 'synci $2'

Comment: I've fixed a couple of typos, so the code should make more sense now.

Comment: Note that `synci` is only available on newer MIPS processors -- MIPS64  has it, and processors that support both MIPS64 and MIPS32 probably have it, but MIPS32-only processors may not.  Older processors have no unprivileged way of doing the necessary cache flush.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, all MIPS32R2 processors have `SYNCI.` MIPS32R2 was introduced in 2003 (as was MIPS64R2), so any MIPS processor less than 10 years old has `SYNCI.` (This instruction was not in MIPS64R1.)

Comment: You need a synci for every cache line that needs to be synchronized.  In this example, the two instructions may end up on different cache lines (depending upon the minimum alignment guarantee of malloc).

Answer (score 2):

You are using pointers inappropriately. Or, to be more accurate, you *aren't* using pointers where you should be.

Try this on for size:

```
uint32_t *addone = malloc(sizeof(*addone) * 2);
addone[0] = 0x20820001; // addi $v0, $a0, 1
addone[1] = 0x23e00000; // jr $ra

int (*f)(int x) = addone; //our function pointer
i = (*f)(i);
printf("%d\n",i);
```

You may also need to set the memory as executable after writing to it, but before calling it:

```
mprotect(addone, sizeof(int) * 2, PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC);
```

To make this work, you may additionally need to allocate a considerably larger block of memory (4k or so) so that the address is page-aligned.

Answer (score 2):

You also need to make sure that the memory in question is executable, and makes sure it gets flushed properly from the dcache after writing it and loaded into the icache before executing it.  How to do that depends on the OS running on your mips machine.

On Linux, you would use the mprotect system call to make the memory executable, and the cacheflush system call to do the cache flushing.

**edit**

Example:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <asm/cachecontrol.h>

#define PALIGN(P)  ((char *)((uintptr_t)(P) & (pagesize-1)))
uintptr_t  pagesize;

void inc(){
    int i = 41;
    uint32_t *addone = malloc(sizeof(*addone) * 2); //we malloc space for our asm function
    *(addone) = 0x20820001; // this is addi $v0 $a0 1, which adds one to our arg (gcc calling con)
    *(addone + 1) = 0x23e00000; //this is jr $ra

    pagesize = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);  // only needs to be done once
    mprotect(PALIGN(addone), PALIGN(addone+1)-PALIGN(addone)+pagesize,
             PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC);
    cacheflush(addone, 2*sizeof(*addone), ICACHE|DCACHE);

    int (*f)(int x) = addone; //our function pointer
    i = (*f)(i);
    printf("%d",i);    
}
```

Note that we make the entire page(s) containing the code both writable and executable.  That's because memory protection works per page, and we want malloc to be able to continue to use the rest of the page(s) for other things.  You could instead use `valloc` or `memalign` to allocate entire pages, in which case you could make the code read-only executable safely.

Answer (score 1):

Calling a function is much more complicated than just jumping to an instruction.

- How are arguments passed? Are they stored in registers, or pushed to the call stack?
- How is a value returned?
- Where is the return address placed for the return jump? If you have a recursive function, `$ra` doesn't cut it.
- Is the caller or the callee responsible for popping the stack frame when the called function completes?

Different [calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) have different answers to these questions. Though I've never tried anything like what you're doing, I would assume you'd have to write your machine code to match a convention, then tell the compiler that your function pointer uses that convention (different compilers have different ways of doing this - [gcc does it with function attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)).

Comment: Hi slavik262. I've editted, and yes, I'm fairly certain the calling con should be working. Tbh, I don't know whether $ra will be set to what I want since I haven't been able to test yet. I've read up on the calling con, my main problem now is I have a no idea (or worse, a mistake and bad idea) of how to call these machine instructions.

Comment: One thing you could do is look at the assembly gcc generates and see what the compiler is trying to do.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Could you elaborate? Obviously something isn't right if things aren't working as desired.

Comment: I don't know how to elaborate "the assembly is correct", but you can look at [MIPS Calling Conventions](http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse410/09sp/examples/MIPSCallingConventionsSummary.pdf) yourself and check page 4 -- it has an example which is almost identical to the one in the question.  If the assembly is correct something else is wrong.

Comment: @slavik262: um, I can't compile... (and hence can't see what's going on).