# Writing ARM machine instructions and executing them from C (On the Raspberry pi)

Tags: c, assembly, arm, jit, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to write some self modifying code in C and ARM. I previously asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162464/writing-mips-machine-instructions-and-executing-them-from-c) about MIPS and am now trying to port over the project to ARM.
My system := Raspbian on raspberry pi, ARMv6, GCC

There are a few things I am unsure of:

- Does ARM require a D-cache write-back/I-cache invalidate (cache flush)? If so, how can we do this?

Also I tried an example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int inc(int x){ //increments x
    uint16_t *ret = malloc(2 * sizeof(uint16_t));

    *(ret + 0) = 0x3001; //add r0 1 := r0 += 1
    *(ret + 1) = 0x4770; //bx lr    := jump back to inc()

    int(*f)(int) = (int (*)(int)) ret;
    return (*f)(x);
}

int main(){
    printf("%d",inc(6)); //expect '7' to be printed
exit(0);}
```

but I keep getting a segmentation fault. I'm using the aapcs calling convention, which I've been given to understand is the default for all ARM

I'd be much obliged if someone pointed me in the right direction

Bonus question (meaning, it doesn't really have to be answered, but would be cool to know) - I "come from a MIPS background", how the heck do ARM programmers do without a 0 register? (as in, a register hardcoded to the value 0)

Comment: this is not an arm or mips question it is a linux and protection question.  Use mmap to allocate the memory space and enable it for execution, etc, then modify that then you can branch to it without a protection fault.  There are many SO questions that already answer the "self modifying code on linux" question, the question has the same answer for mips, arm, x86, ppc, etc.

Comment: As to your bonus question: the ARM has the most extended ways to enter constants into the datapath of the processor, of all the processors I know (around 10), so why bother with just 0. So my counter question would be: why the heck does the MIPS wast instruction encoding space of one register to just get a 0 into the datapath? A rhetorical question of course.

Comment: @dwelch: Sorry, you're not very convincing. See the link I added (similar question); The answer wasn't the same for MIPS.
But getting back to the question, are you saying that you know for ARM the only way to go is with mmap?

Comment: @BryanOlivier: I guess I have to clock more hours coding in assembly then =) As a bonus bonus I don't suppose you'd show the "standard" way to set a register to 1? (ie, the ARM equivalent of the MIPS addi $t0, $0, 1)

Comment: @artlessnoise: Yes, Thumb-2 the documentation tells me. Did I encode my instructions wrong? I'm using the ARMv6-M Architecture Reference Manual.

I did come across something strange. The manual seemed to be saying that
    `bx lr`
has unpredictable behaviour. I didn't know what to make of that and so ignored it.

Comment: @C.E.Sally  Your thumb instructions look good.  I just wonder if you started in `thumb` mode.  Ie, if you are initially in ARM mode and jump to a `thumb` routine without switching modes, you will crash.

Comment: You need at least, `int tmp = 0; /* Drain WB */ __asm volatile(" mcr p15, 0, %0, c7, c10, 4\n" : "=r" (tmp));` to ensure that the writes are committed to RAM before jumping.

Comment: @artlessnoise: Ah... I'm not to sure about that(the mode switching I mean). The impression I got is that the Pi would basically always be in Thumb mode (I got this impression from the ARMv6-M manual. Is that correct?)  
Could you add a little colour on the mcr instruction? When I did a quick google, it seemed to come up a bit, but when I looked through the technical documentation I couldn't find it.

I also don't quite understand your code, could you elaborate or perhaps point me in the direction of documentation? Also, if you made it an answer I could accept.

Comment: @C.E.Sally For the bonus bonus that would be `MOV Rd,#1` and that will work for any 8-bit value. The nice part is that if you need to set additional bits, you can OR them in while rotating the original 8 bits to an arbitrary location in the register. With `MVN` you can set 8 zero bits.

Comment: Also, you'll want to allocate executable memory. Memory allocated through malloc might not be guaranteed to executable since it's supposed to be data and not code. Try allocating memory using mmap and setting the executable flag. Here's an answer I wrote for x86 (but should work under ARM too) http://stackoverflow.com/a/14826557/268025 Edit: Beaten - just saw dwelch's comment.

Comment: @artlessnoise: I'm still getting a segmentation fault even with that. Also, if ARMv6-M only supports thumb2, do we need to change it to `mcrr`?

Comment: You cannot execute a page which doesnt have the permission. You should use mmap with right flags not malloc.

Comment: There is a zero register in arm, wzr. http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.den0024a/ch05s01s03.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [Caches and Self-Modifying Code](http://blogs.arm.com/software-enablement/141-caches-and-self-modifying-code/) on `blogs.arm.com`. Article includes an example as well which does what you are describing.

To answer your question from article

> > ... the ARM architecture is often considered to be a Modified Harvard Architecture. ...
> >
> > The typical drawback of a pure Harvard architecture is that instruction memory is not directly accessible from the same address space as data memory, though this restriction does not apply to ARM. **On ARM, you can write instructions into memory, but because the D-cache and I-cache are not coherent, the newly-written instructions might be masked by the existing contents of the I-cache, causing the processor to execute old (or possibly invalid) instructions.**

See [__clear_cache](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) for how to invalidate cache(s).

I hope you are also aware of ARM/Thumb instruction sets, if you are planning to push your instructions into memory.

Comment: I'm aware that there are ARM and thumb but now I'm having a hard time trying to understand if the set up I have can run in arm. The documentation seems to be saying for ARMv6-M, only thumb is available

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so this works on my raspberry Pi.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int inc(int x){ //increments x

    uint32_t *ret = mmap(NULL,
            2 * sizeof(uint32_t),  // Space for 16 instructions. (More than enough.)
            PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC,
            MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS,
            -1,0);
    if (ret == MAP_FAILED) {
        printf("Could not mmap a memory buffer with the proper permissions.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    *(ret + 0) = 0xE2800001; //add r0 r0 #1 := r0 += 1
    *(ret + 1) = 0xE12FFF1E; //bx lr        := jump back to inc()

    __clear_cache((char*) ret, (char*) (ret+2));

    int(*f)(int) = (int (*)(int)) ret;
    return (*f)(x);
}

int main(){
    printf("%d\n",inc(6)); //expect '7' to be printed
exit(0);}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this sample code. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems.

1. You don't flush your D-Cache and I-Cache, so most times the I-Cache will fetch stale data from L2. Under linux there is a libc/sys-call which does that for you. Either use __clear_cache(begin, end) or _*builtin*_clear_cache(begin, end).
2. You output Thumb-Code, but you don't take care of how your code gets called. The easiest way to fix that would be to use some asm-code to do the actual blx call and OR the address with 1, as this bit sets the mode the processor runs in. As you're malloc address will always be aligned to a word boundary, making you call thumb-code in arm-mode.

Comment: The impression I'm getting from the documentation is that thumb instructions are halfword aligned, so if my block of memory is word aligned I'll be good?

I also don't yet understand what you mean about setting the thumb mode. Again from the documentation, the impression I'm getting, is that I'll always be in thumb mode for ARMv6-M

Comment: As for the cache coherrence, I've tried both but unfortunately am still seg faulting, so I think I have another problem elsewhere